# Does Meteor.call affect optimistic UI?

Tags: meteor, minimongo, optimistic-ui

When I do a Meteor.call instead of a direct collection manipulation on both client and server. Does it remove the optimistic UI changes, aka minimongo changes and simply does direct to server change and wait for update on server before updating the UI?

Comment: This is unclear. A `Meteor.call` can execute absolutely any kind of code. I suspect you are doing database updates in this call, but I can't be sure. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your client and server code.

Comment: For example if I do a call to remove a user. And on the page there is a table that displays table. If I were to do this via a client helper it will show instantly and also run the same action on the server. But if I do a Meteor.call instead, does that still happen?

Answer (score 5):

[Read the last section of this Meteor doc about 'How latency compensation works'](https://www.meteor.com/full-stack-db-drivers)

**In Summary**

You do lose optimistic data changes as you suspected if your Meteor.method is defined server-side only. In this case, when your client calls the method, you are essentially calling an REST service and waiting for the server-side response before your client can process the response.

When you do a client-side collection manipulation, client-side simulates the changes in minimongo, then tells the server to change the collection, then server updates the client with the server side changes (accepted or rejected).

*Note: If you share Meteor.method to client and server, you can get optimistic nature. I've never done this, but read the link*